# how to grep a N (7) column row before a grepped number from a long text file

Tags: awk, grep

I have a text file with a spacial format.
After the top "N" rows, the file will have a 7 column row ans then there will be "X" rows (X is the value from column number 6 in this 7 column row). Then there will be another row with 7 column and it will have further "Y" sub-rows (Y is the value from column number 6 in this 7 column row). and it occurance of rows will go upto some fixed numbers, say 40.
En example is here
(I am skipping top few rows).

```
  2.857142857143E-01 2.857142857143E-01-2.857142857143E-01         1  1533   9  1.0
           1  -3.52823873905418
           2  -3.52823873905417
           3  -1.77620635653680
           4  -1.77620635653680
           5  -1.77620570068355
           6  -1.77620570068354
           7  -1.77620570066112
           8  -1.77620570066112
           9  -1.60388273192418

 1.428571428571E-01 1.428571428571E-01-1.428571428571E-01         2  1506   14  8.0
           1  -3.52823678441811
           2  -3.52823678441810
           3  -1.77620282216865
           4  -1.77620282216865
           5  -1.77619365786042
           6  -1.77619365786042
           7  -1.77619324280126
           8  -1.77619324280125
           9  -1.60387130881086
          10  -1.60387130881086
          11  -1.60387074066972
          12  -1.60387074066972
          13  -1.51340357895078
          14  -1.51340357895078
 1.000000000000E+00 4.285714285714E-01-1.428571428571E-01        20  1524   51 24.0
           1  -3.52823580096110     
           2  -3.52823580096109     
           3  -1.77624472106293     
           4  -1.77624472106293     
           5  -1.77623455229910     
           6  -1.77623455229909     
           7  -1.77620473017160     
           8  -1.77620473017159     
           9  -1.60387169115834     
          10  -1.60387169115834     
          11  -1.60386634866654     
          12  -1.60386634866654     
          13  -1.51340851656332     
          14  -1.51340851656332     
          15  -1.51340086887553     
          16  -1.51340086887553     
          17  -1.51321967923767     
          18  -1.51321967923766     
          19  -1.40212716813452     
          20  -1.40212716813451     
          21  -1.40187887062753     
          22  -1.40187887062753     
          23 -0.749391485667459     
          24 -0.749391485667455     
          25 -0.740712218931955     
          26 -0.740712218931954     
          27 -0.714030906779278     
          28 -0.714030906779278     
          29 -0.689087278411268     
          30 -0.689087278411265     
          31 -0.687054399753234     
          32 -0.687054399753233     
          33 -0.677686868127079     
          34 -0.677686868127075     
          35 -0.405343895324740     
          36 -0.405343895324739     
          37 -0.404786479693490     
          38 -0.404786479693488     
          39 -0.269454266134757     
          40 -0.269454266134755     
          41 -0.267490250650300     
          42 -0.267490250650296     
          43 -0.262198373307171     
          44 -0.262198373307170     
          45 -0.260912148881762     
          46 -0.260912148881761     
          47 -9.015623907768122E-002
          48 -9.015623907767983E-002
          49  0.150591609452852     
          50  0.150591609452856     
          51  0.201194203960446
```

I want to grep a particular number from my text file and to do so, I use

```
awk -v c=2 -v t=$GREP 'NR==1{d=$c-t;d=d<0?-d:d;v=$c;next}{m=$c-t;m=m<0?-m:m}m<d{d=m;v=$c}END{print v}' case.dat
Here $GREP is 0.2011942 which prints the last row (it will change according to different file)

51  0.201194203960446
```

I want to print the header row also with this number, i.e., my script should print,

```
51  0.201194203960446
1.000000000000E+00 4.285714285714E-01-1.428571428571E-01        20  1524   51 24.0.
```

How can I print this header row of the grepped numbers?

I have idea, but I could not implement it in script format.
**Simply, grep the number using my script and print the first row before this number that have 7 columns.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be what you're looking for

```
awk -v t="$GREP" '
    BEGIN             { sub("\\.", "\\.", t) }
    NF > 2            { header=$0; next }
    NF == 2 && $2 ~ t { printf("%s %s\n%s\n", $1, $2, header) }
' file
```

You can replace the `NF > 2` with `NF == 7` if you want the strictly seven-column header to be printed (that header contains 6 columns in your sample data, not 7).

---

Update after the comment "Can you please modify my script so that it should grep upto 13 decimal number":

```
awk -v t="$GREP" '
    BEGIN             { if (match(t, "\\.")) {
                            t = substr(t, 1, RSTART + 13)
                            sub("\\.", "\\.", t)
                        }
                      }
    NF > 2            { header=$0; next }
    NF == 2 && $2 ~ t { printf("%s %s\n%s\n", $1, $2, header) }
' file
```

Comment: Can you please modify my script so that it should grep upto 13 decimal numbers. Because 14th and 15th digit may vary in two similar number while I want to print both of them

Comment: Example: My grep command gives 0.727510083482439 while in next column I have 0.727510083482441, So I want to restrict my grep upto 13th decimal to print both the numbers.

Comment: You are right, my header row has six column. Because the second and third columns are not separated. I do not know how to consider them separated.

Comment: I wanted to restrict my script `awk -v c=2 -v t=$GREP 'NR==1{d=$c-t;d=d<0?-d:d;v=$c;next}{m=$c-t;m=m<0?-m:m}m<d{d=m;v=$c}END{print v}' case.dat` in such a way that it should print only 13 decimal numbers.